# Gruntjs + nodemon

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I keep getting the error show in the image when running nodemon with watch & node inspector with the sails.js framework

Anyone come across this before??
[image]

Answer (score 2):

EADDRINUSE means the port the server try to bind is currently in use.

In this case, your port 1337  and 3000 have been occupied by other server already. You should change your configuration or kill the processes that occupy the ports.

Comment: Port 1337 is node-inspector and 300 is the app. It looks like the server is not stopping before restating. This is using sailsjs using watch, nodemon for auto restarted when changes are made to server files